# How to trigger an event without natural pressing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the click to be executed by #tab-1, thus the onClick event was executed, how do I do it?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var tavName = $("#tab-1");
    //$("#tab-1").trigger('click');
    var tb = document.getElementById('tab-1');
    tb.addEventListener(onClick);
    $('.tabs-inpts').on('click', function onClick(e) {
        tavName = ('.' + this.id);
        console.log(this.id);
        console.log(tavName);
        $(this).off(e); 
    });
});
```

```
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-1" checked>
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-2">
<input class="tabs-inpts" type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-3">

<form class="tab-1 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
<form class="tab-2 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
<form class="tab-3 tab" name="form" method="post">
  ***other content***
</form>
```

At start in the console should be:
tab-1
.tab-1

Comment: You have the right click trigger code in there, why is it commented out?

Comment: because it doesn't work

Comment: You called `trigger()` before you set the event listener you cant trigger something that hasnt been setup yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the code like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tab-1").trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: OP is already doing this, `jQuery(function(){})` is an alias / shortcut for calling `$(document).ready()`